# Why is the "me" used in "Me explotó una bomba a pocos metros de la cabeza"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, pronombres

In the following sentence from [a Duolingo podcast](https://podcast.duolingo.com/episode-3-memorias-y-milanesas) why is "me explotó" used?

> **Me** explotó una bomba a pocos metros de la cabeza.
>   <sub>A bomb exploded a few metres from my head</sub>

Why is the "me" needed?

Comment: This has been already answered (see link above). It's a sympathetic dative. In short, *me* signals that *la cabeza* belongs to the speaker.

Comment: Notice that in your sentence the determiner "la" has been translated to "my", but its equivalent in English is "the". If you got "A bomb exploded a few metres from the head" Whose head? That's why "me" appears there. More detailed info in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

> **Me** explotó una bomba a pocos metros de la cabeza.
>   <sub>A bomb exploded a few metres from my head</sub>
>
> Why is the "me" needed?

If you don't put that `Me` there, it's not clear whose head is.

You would have to construct a different sentence, such as `Una bomba explotó a pocos metros de mi cabeza.`. Note the `mi` in the alternative construction.

Hope that helped.